# Invoke a service after windows forms loading

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have an mobile application (.NET CF2 for Windows Mobile 6.1) that starts right after the system startup.

I want to force the form to load and them call a web service. there`s also a button that invokes the WS mannually.

I haven`t managed to first load the form so far. First it invokes the service and them it shows the form up.

Can you help me?

Bellow the code I`m using.

//MAIN FORM OF THE APP

using System;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace AtualizaColetores
{
    public partial class frmInicio : Form
    {
        public frmInicio()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Program.ShowHide.ShowTopStatusbar(false);



            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                //incia animação para indicar processamento em segundo plano
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                Cursor.Show();

                Atualizador executar = new Atualizador();
                executar.AtualizaColetor();
            });


            try
            {
                Process firstProc = new Process();
                firstProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"\WOPT\RF_WOPT.exe";
                firstProc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                firstProc.Start();

                firstProc.WaitForExit();
                this.Activate();
                Form destino = new frmControles();
                destino.Show();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro na incialização do programa: " + ex.Message);
                return;
            }




            //Para a animação para indicar processamento em segundo plano
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            Cursor.Show();
        }


    }
}
```

//Center code hereODE TO DOWNLOAD AND REPLACE THE CURRENT VERSION OF THE APP, IF NEEDED

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

using System.Xml;
using Ionic.Zip;

namespace AtualizaColetores
{
    class Atualizador
    {
        public void AtualizaColetor()
        {

            if (File.Exists(@"\WOPT\About.xml"))
            {
                string versaoAplicativo = "", LocalAplicativo = "", tipoColetor = "";

                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(@"\WOPT\About.xml");

                XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("VersaoRF");

                foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
                {
                    versaoAplicativo = xn["versaoAplicativo"].InnerText;
                    LocalAplicativo = xn["localAplicativo"].InnerText;
                    tipoColetor = xn["tipoColetor"].InnerText;
                }

                ConectorWOPT.WOPT executar = new ConectorWOPT.WOPT();

                //inserir tratamento de erro aqui.
                byte[] arquivo = executar.AtualizaColetores(LocalAplicativo, versaoAplicativo, tipoColetor);

                string caminhoWOPT = @"\WOPT";

                if (arquivo.Length > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arquivo);
                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(
                        @"\novaVersao.zip", FileMode.Create);
                        ms.WriteTo(fs);
                        ms.Close();
                        fs.Close();
                        fs = null;
                        ms = null;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }

                    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(caminhoWOPT))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            System.IO.Directory.Delete(caminhoWOPT, true);

                            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(caminhoWOPT))
                            {
                                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(caminhoWOPT);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                        }
                    }

                    if (File.Exists(@"\novaVersao.zip"))
                    {
                        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(@"\novaVersao.zip"))
                        {
                            foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
                            {
                                e.Extract(@"\WOPT\", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);  // overwrite == true
                            }
                        }
                        System.IO.File.Delete(@"\novaVersao.zip");

                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Coletor atualizado com sucesso");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Falha na atualização");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("O aplicativo não está instalado neste coletor. Contate um supervisor.");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delay the processing with a timer or thread.  Something along these lines:

```
public frmInicio()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Program.ShowHide.ShowTopStatusbar(false);

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // or however long you need
        btnZip_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    });
}
```

Or put the call in `OnActivate`, checking for a first run.

**EDIT 1**

You have a lot (too much IMO) going on in your constructors.  I'm betting the Form visibility issue has a lot to do with the fact that you are creating a Process in your Form constructor and then waiting for that process to complete before continuing.  If that app is waiting on the output of your web service call, the thread creation was pointless because you've still made the constructor serially dependent on the call.

Comment: I`ll try this. I thought in using this option but it not seemed 'elegant' to me. If it works and no one suggests something different,  i`ll mark yours as the awsnser! tks.

Comment: ctacke is right. AFAIK there is no way to 'know' when a compact framework form is really displayed.

Comment: This solution isn`t working, unfortunately... the form is only displayed after thw WS call. I really need to first show the form and then call the WS...

Comment: We'd have to see your code.  Using a thread or a timer makes the call asynchronous and if it's still keeping the Form from showing, you have something else going on.