# Windows CE click bug

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce

In my application I have a few situations where there is a short momentary delay switching between forms, and although I briefly display a wait cursor, any taps the user makes during this transition register on the yet to be displayed form. 
Has anyone else noticed this problem, and if so how have you gone about fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a similar issue as in [avoid click event while panel is refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448825/avoid-click-event-while-panel-is-refreshing/13475364#13475364) and [Invoke a service after windows forms loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972921/invoke-a-service-after-windows-forms-loading)

You have to ignore messages a while in the new form. There is no "Form is really visibe" in compact framework.

You can disable all controls in a form and have a timer that enables the controls after some delay, which more or less ensures that the form will not receive input as long it is not fully visible.

Sorry, but there is no better solution then using some delay as there is no event that can be used to verify the form has been fully loaded and is visible to the user.

Comment: Thanks, using peekMessage was my first guess, but I thought there had to be a better way. I should know better by now :P